# What's SQL Server equivalent of Oracle Sequence.nextval

Tags: sql-server

Question: I have now SQL Server database for Maximo Schema. (Earlier I have worked with Oracle database for the same). What Is the SQL Server equivalent for Oracle Sequence.Nextval ? If someone can help me please.

While inserting a record with unique id (tkstatusid), we have tried MAX(ID)+1 but it gives chance for duplication. I believe, similar to the sequence.nextval in Oracle, there will be a location in SQL Server, where the next number or last number is saved in.

Comment: You can Use Auto_Increment

Comment: @ Damien: Yes it is about SQL server. I hv the changed the tag. thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Create a sequence like this

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Schema.SequenceName
AS int
INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

Then you can use sequence in your Insert statement like below

```
Insert into Schema.tableName (table_id) values (NEXT VALUE FOR Schema.SequenceName)
```

Answer (score 0):

in MS SQL it's SCOPE_IDENTITY(), if you want to get the last inserted auto-id

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(ValueField) VALUES('New Value'); 
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS MyNewIdNumber;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: Dear Weissvonnix, Thanks. Could you explain is this a table to be queried (SCOPE_IDENTITY). I cannot find this as a table in my database. Please advise.

Comment: Could you give a simple sample query

Comment: `scope_identity` is the equivalent for `currval`, not `nextval`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sequence` then it is supported by ORACLE and SQL Server both.

Otherwise you can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` for last `inserted id`. It is better practice to use `SEQUENCE` rather than `SCOPE_IDENTITY.`

Comment: We are using Maximo7.5. In database, I am not able to see SEQUENCE or SCOPE_IDENTITY. Could you give a small sample query to insert a new TKSTATUS with TKSTATUSID. If you don't mind.

Comment: I m extremely sorry, but i have no idea for MAXIMO.

Answer (score -1):

you should upgrade your sql server version to 2012 or higher.
you can see complete information about it in below link:

[create sequence in sql server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT max(ISNULL(xx.xx.xxxxxxxx.id,0)) + 1 FROM xx.xx.xxxxxxxx)
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `max (ISNULL(field_value,0)) + 1`